# Scala checkstyle - Ignoring specific files for check

Tags: scala, checkstyle, scalastyle

I've got a `scalastyle_config.xml` file with the following check, among others:

```
<check class="org.scalastyle.scalariform.ClassNamesChecker" level="warning" enabled="false">
   <parameters>
         <parameter name="regex"><![CDATA[^[A-Z][A-Za-z]*$]]></parameter>
   </parameters>
</check>
```

I want this to be applied to all files, except for two:

```
-FooK3.java
-FooK3Something.java
```

Is there any way to add an exception for those files? Can't see anything in the [documentation](http://www.scalastyle.org/)

Comment: Maybe you could just add them to regex? For example: `^[A-Z][A-Za-z]*$|^FooK3$|^FooK3Something$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any way to exclude specific files from that checker, and I've been using `scalastyle` for a while, so I assume there isn't such a way at the moment.

What can be done, is turning off `scalastyle` exactly where you don't want it. And then it will work on the rest of the file. For example where you define `Class FooK3`, you can do either:

```
class FooK3 { // scalastyle:ignore
```

Or:

```
// scalastyle:off
public class FooK3 {
// scalastyle:on
  int x = 5;
}
```

Then the check will pass. A good practice is the add to the comment the name of the rule you want to bypass, such that if one day someone fixes it, `scalastyle` will be returned.

Official docs can be found [here](http://www.scalastyle.org/configuration.html).